# Comparing files in two folders with different hierarchies and renamed files

Tags: windows-7, linux, sync, comparison, duplicate

I had a folder on my PC, and copied it to my laptop. Since than, I have changed some files on each of 
the folders (file modification, renaming, putting into folders an vice versa).

How can I re-sync the two folders? (preferably in windows).

Note: Obviously, it requires something like a duplicate finder. I can put both folders in a single machine and perform a duplicate remover to delete the duplicates. However, since most of the files (99%) are not changed, this solution seems inefficient. So I ideally want a result in this format:

```
1. 0553423.jpg --> portraints/portrait.jpg (Renamed and moved to the folder).
2. 2010/3930.jpg --> sig.jpg (Renamed and moved to the parent folder).
3. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout microsoft's synctoy application, you can use it to sync two directories unidirectional or bidirectional